# What is the RNP requirement within the KZAK FIR?

Tags: faa-regulations

What's the RNP requirement with KZAK FIR?
I thought it is RNP 10 operating in NOPAC AND PACOTS, but I am not sure.

Comment: Related: [ICAO - Overview of Oceanic and Continental Remote Navigation Specifications](http://www.icao.int/safety/pbn/seminar%20material/montreal,%20canada%2013-15%20june%202007/b.2.pdf). RNAV-10 prescribed, RNP-4 optional (and no authorization required).

Answer (score 1):

To be exact *RNAV 10* is required when operating in the KZAK FIR. This enables 50NM longitudinal and lateral separation between aircrafts.

Unfortunately, the requirement might be designated *RNP 10* due to legacy reasons. The difference between *RNAV* and *RNP* is that *RNAV* requires no onboard performance monitoring and alerting capability, while, among other things, *RNP* does.

*RNP 4* is optional to allow closer 30NM longitudinal and lateral separation between *RNP 4* capable/authorized aircraft thus increasing the airspace capacity.

Sources:

- [ICAO Doc 9613 - *Performance-based Navigation (PBN) Manual*](https://www.icao.int/SAM/Documents/2009/SAMIG3/PBN%20Manual%20-%20Doc%209613%20Final%205%2010%2008%20with%20bookmarks1.pdf)
- [ICAO Doc 8168 - *Procedures for Air Navigation Services — Aircraft Operations, Volume I (PANS-OPS Vol I)*](http://code7700.com/pdfs/icao_doc_8168_vol_1.pdf)